# I'm able to access private variables outside the class definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript, the problem is I'm able to access the private variables outside the class definition which is against the concept of class. However, I came across similar questions but I want someone who can explain what is wrong in my code.

```
class Car {
    constructor(private brand?: string, private model?: string) {
    }
    car_detail = function() {
        console.log("Brand -> " + this.brand + " Model -> " + this.model);
    }
}

let obj_mg = new Car("MG", "Gloster");
obj_mg.car_detail();
```

I've attached the output screenshot below for your reference.
[image: output that i got after transpilation]

Comment: you've provided a public method on the class which uses private properties.  You're not accessing the private properties directly. This is how classes usually work. public API that uses private properties. If you try to directly read or assign to `brand` or `model` on `obj_mg`, like `obj_mg.brand`, you will see an error

Answer (score 0):

By default methods are public. You should declare it private if you dont want to access the method outside class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `car_detail` method is public by default unless specified. you are calling the method itself, which has access to the properties and that's normal behaviour.

Having access to private properties means you could do `obj_mg.model` (model and brand being private properties)

https://coryrylan.com/blog/private-methods-and-properties-in-typescript-classes